# Как сделать всплывающие окно по событию event(QEvent *e)

Tags: c++, qt

Попытаюсь объяснить. Есть у меня событие по подключению USB флешки. Как только USB флешка подключена вызывается событие по которому можно детектировать подключение или отключение флешки. Как только вызывается событие должно появляться окно поверх других окон с фокусировкой в центре с возможностью управления "запись чтение определенных файлов".

Как можно сделать?

Comment: так в чем вопрос то? если как вы пишите обработчик события уже есть

Comment: Вопрос как привязать окно к этому событию? И вызывать его поверх любого окна  с фокусировкой. Надеюсь понятно сказал.

Comment: Для создания окна поверх других вам судя по всему надо модальное окно, которые в кьют реализуются классом QDialog (метод exec()). Вам надо пронаследоваться от QDialog (добавить там контролы и т.п.) и по наступлению вашего события создавать диалог и вызывать метод exec. Не понятно как реализовано ваше событие, но думаю, его без проблем можно обернуть в стандартную для кьют систему сигнал-слот

Comment: Отловить сигнал достаточно просто думаю даже не стоит объяснять, а по поводу вызова окна. Необходимо создать модальное(в случае если не нужно больше проверять флешки) окно в котором будет какое то наполнение. Сигнал прикрутить тоже нет проблем, а вызвать окно по верх других на сколько я помню за это отвечает нужный флаг Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint, для функции setWindowFlags для модального окна.